# Как реализовать этот метод на чистом js

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

```
$('#el').bind('click change input', function(e){

});
```

то есть повесить много событий на один элемент ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function doSomething() {
  ...
}

var el = document.getElementById('el')
['click', 'change', 'input'].forEach( function(event) {
  el.addEventListener(event, doSomething(), false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function yourFunc() {}

const elem = document.getElementById('el');
elem.addEventListener('click', yourFunc);
elem.addEventListener('change', yourFunc);
elem.addEventListener('input', yourFunc);
```